# Parallel edge detection

Tags: graph, adjacency-list

I am working on a problem (from *Algorithms* by Sedgewick, section 4.1, problem [32](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/)) to help my understanding, and I have no idea how to proceed.

"Parallel edge detection. Devise a linear-time algorithm to count the parallel edges in a (multi-)graph.
*Hint:* maintain a boolean array of the neighbors of a vertex, and reuse this array by only reinitializing the entries as needed."

Where two edges are considered to be parallel if they connect the same pair of vertices

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: What have you tried? Don't worry about getting O(n) for now, just try to count the parallel edges. How would you do it?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the obvious way of doing it. Assuming I have an adjacency list, I loop through to each element of the list and count the number of repetitions, I also skip the double counts

Comment: Without more information about your definition of a graph no-one is going to be give you a good answer. A graph is a set of vertices and edges G = (V, E), but there is no notion of anything geometric that goes with that. Is the graph embedded in a lattice? If so what type (square, triangular, other?).

Comment: The graph is given as an adjacency list. Meaning, this is a 2d array where each (i,J) denotes if the two vertices have an edge between them.

Comment: also assume the graph is undirected and simple

Comment: Hold on there. An adjacency list is a *list*, in which each entry corresponds to one or more edges between a particular pair of nodes. A 2d array in which each entry (i,j) contains some information about the edges (if any) between node i and node j is something very different. If you use the list to construct the array, you can count the parallel edges along the way, and in linear time (O(n)).

Comment: **Wait a minute!** If it's a *simple* graph as you say, then we can count the parallel edges in O(1), before we even see the list! I think you ought to review your terminology, because as it stands this question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, it is a multigraph*, my apologies.

Comment: Beta--If for each vertex n you have an adjacency list (which is what I am describing--an adjacency matrix), then how would you find the total number of parallel edges?

Comment: My question is found here under "creative problems" http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use BFS for this.

Main idea is to be able to tell if two or more paths exist between two nodes or not, so for this, we can use a set and see if adjacent nodes corresponding to a Node's adjacent list already are in the set.

This uses O(n) extra space but has O(n) time complexity.

```
boolean bfs(int start){

 Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();       // get a Queue
 boolean[] mark = new boolean[num_of_vertices]; 
 mark[start] = true;                            // put 1st node into Queue
 q.add(start); 
 while(!q.isEmpty()){
    int current = q.remove();
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(); /* use a hashset for 
                                    storing nodes of current adj. list*/ 
    ArrayList<Integer> adjacentlist= graph.get(current);   // get adj. list 
    for(int x : adjacentlist){
        if(set.contains(x){  // if it already had a edge current-->x
          return true;       // then we have our parallel edge
        }
        else set.add(x);     // if not then we have a new edge 

        if(!marked[x]){      // normal bfs routine
            mark[x]=true;
            q.add(x);
        }
    }
 }
}// assumed graph has ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> representation    
 // undirected
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the vertices in your graph are integers `0 .. |V|`.

If your graph is directed, edges in the graph are denoted `(i, j)`.

This allows you to produce a unique mapping of any edge to an integer (a hash function) which can be found in O(1).

```
h(i, j) = i * |V| + j
```

You can insert/lookup the tuple `(i, j)` in a hash table in amortised O(1) time. For `|E|` edges in the adjacency list, this means the total running time will be O(|E|) or linear in the number of edges in the adjacency list.

A python implementation of this might look something like this:

```
def identify_parallel_edges(adj_list):
    # O(n) list of edges to counts
    # The Python implementation of tuple hashing implements a more sophisticated
    # version of the approach described above, but is still O(1)
    edges = {}
    for edge in adj_list:
        if edge not in edges:
            edges[edge] = 0
        edges[edge] += 1

    # O(n) filter non-parallel edges
    res = []
    for edge, count in edges.iteritems():
        if count > 1:
            res.append(edge)
    return res

edges = [(1,0),(2,1),(1,0),(3,4)]
print identify_parallel_edges(edges)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by (i, j) = (min(i,j), max(i,j)). The graph I am dealing with is undirected

Comment: Also the data structures I am dealing with are arrays (adjacency lists or matrices)